# Can someone explain how does this slicing work?

Tags: python

```
x=[1,2,3,4]

In [91]: x[:1]
Out[91]: [1]
```

x[:n] select up to 'n' (exclusive) columns?

```
In [93]: x[:-1]
Out[93]: [1, 2, 3]
```

How does `x[:-1]` work?

```
In [94]: x[::-1]
Out[94]: [4, 3, 2, 1]
```

And what about `x[::-1]`? There are two `::` here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x[start:stop:step]` is the basic format
If any of the three are not specified, they take the default values, `start = 0, stop = just after last element, step = 1`
According to string indexing, x[1] is the second index and x[-1] is the last index.

1. So, x[:1] => x[0:1:1] which means all from 0 to 1 not including 1
   with an interval of 1.
2. Similarly, x[:-1] => x[0:-1:1] which is
   basically x from 0 (begin) up to -1 (end) not including -1 with a
   step of 1
3. Lastly, x[::-1] goes through the whole string from start
   to end but it uses a step of -1 so it works a little special and
   gives you x[-1: before begin: -1] i.e. from the end to the begin not
   including the one before the start (no index for that one)

Comment: Why isn't x[-0] the last index? because x[0] is the firs index.

Comment: Because x[-0] would still be x[0] which has a different meaning. Reverse indexing starts at -1 and ends at -length while normal indexing goes from 0 to length-1

Answer (score 1):

- `x[:1]` gets the all the values that index is smaller than `1` (so basically just get zeroth element)
- `x[:-1]` gets all values until last value
- `x[::-1]` reverses the list

Comment: How does the last one reverse?

Comment: @user697911 Because `::`,`x[::2]` gets every second value, so `x[::-1]` gets every negative first value, so just somewhat reverses it

Answer (score 1):

You can imagine Python slice `x[start:end]` as an interval `[start, end)`. Besides, missed sign can be `0` or `len(x)`.

`x = [1, 2, 3, 4]`

- `x[:1]` is `x[0:1]` and it's `[0]`
- `x[:-1]` is `x[0:len(x)-1]` and it's `[1, 2, 3]`
- `x[::-1]` is a reversed x and it's `[4, 3, 2, 1]`